# MySQL unique constraint with NULL treated as equal to all other values

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I'm using MySQL 5.7.6 and I need to create an unusual composite unique index on my table.

I need a unique constraint on 2 columns. However, if the 1st column is NULL, I want no other rows to be allowed with the same 2nd column.

### Accepted:

a)

```
context | color
===============
1       | red
2       | red
```

b)

```
context | color
===============
1       | red
1       | blue
```

c)

```
context | color
===============
NULL    | red
NULL    | blue
```

### Rejected:

d)

```
context | color
===============
1       | red
1       | red
```

e)

```
context | color
===============
1       | red
NULL    | red
```

f)

```
context | color
===============
NULL    | red
NULL    | red
```

If needed, I can replace NULL with any other special value, like 0.

Comment: Cond `e` is the most trickiest.

Comment: It is. Everything else is basic.